# How to move Angular Component throughout the page

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, angular-components

I'm pretty new to the Angular framework and I'm making an app with a bunch of Angular components. Right now I'm trying to do a Search Page where I have an input for searching characters, and then after you've picked one of the lists it will show the character's stats card.

So what I want is to move both the search input and the card which appears after selecting a character in the middle of the screen, instead of having them both positioned at the left side of the screen.

Here is a picture that shows what I want to accomplish:

[image]

Here is my code right now (might be a bit messy but I just started like a month and a half ago learning JS, HTML, and CSS):

Search Component Template =>

```
  <div fxLayot="column">
    <div style="background: #4c4848" class="detailContainer">
       <h1>Buscador de Personajes:</h1>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxLayot="column">
        <form class="autocomplete-form">
    <mat-form-field class="enable-full-width" style="background: #4c4848; border-radius: 5px; border: 4px solid black;">
      <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="searchInput"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="search()">
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedOption($event)" [displayWith]="checkValue">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let character of suggestions" [value]="character">
          {{character.name}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngIf="characters.length === 0 && searchInput.value.trim().length>0" value="">
          ERROR 404 - No se encontró nada con el término "{{searchInput.value}}".
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

  </form>
</div>
```

```
<span class="middler"></span>
<div *ngIf="selectedCharacter" fxLayout="column" style="width: 400px;">
    <app-character-card [character]="selectedCharacter"></app-character-card>
</div>
```

(Don't know why they appear in distinct code blocks sorry for that)

Search Component CSS =>

```
.autocomplete-form {
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .enable-full-width {
    width: 500px;
  }

  .detailContainer {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .centered {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Character Card Component Template =>

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title class="charname">{{character.name}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle class="charage">{{character.age}}</mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card-header>
<img mat-card-image [src]="character | image">
<mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-title>{{character.race}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{character.class}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <hr>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="30px">
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Fuerza: </strong>{{character.strength}}
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Inteligencia: </strong>{{character.intelligence}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="30px">          
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Destreza: </strong>{{character.dexterity}}
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Carisma: </strong>{{character.charisma}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="30px">  
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Constitución: </strong>{{character.constitution}}
            </div>       
            <div fxFlex="50">
                <strong>Sabiduría: </strong>{{character.wisdom}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</mat-card-content>

<mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button color="warn" [routerLink]="['..', character.characterId]">
        Leer Más
    </button>
    <button mat-button color="info" [routerLink]="['../../editcharacter', character.characterId]">
        Editar
    </button>
    <a mat-button color="info" [routerLink]="['../..', character.userId, character.characterId, 'inventory']">
        Inventario
    </a>
</mat-card-actions>
```

Character Card Component CSS =>

```
  mat-card {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  img {
    height: 500px;
  }

  .charname, .charage {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .header-image {
    background-image: url('././assets/d20.png');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

I really just need them positioned in the center. I also have this problem in my ItemSearchComponent, but I suppose If I can't answer this, I could easily extrapolate to the other one. Thanks!

If you need any more code just ask.

Comment: Are the typos `fxLayot` present only here or in the code too?

Comment: yeah my bad, already changed those but those aren't the problem x)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that put the search and the results-of-the-search on the same DIV, in "row mode" one below the other, then center that DIV horizontally with many methods out there I usually go for `display:flex`

```html
<div class="head">
    buscador de personajes
</div>
<div class="searchContainer">
    <div class="searchVertical">
       <div class="border">your<br>SearchBox</div>
       <div class="border">search<br>Resuts</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.searchContainer {
    width: 100% ;
    display: flex ;
    justify-content: center;
}

.searchVertical {
    display:flex ;
    flex-direction: column; 
} 

.border {
    border : 1px red solid ; 
}

.head {
    width: 100% ;
    border: 1px green solid ;
}
```

This is how it looks [image]
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-center-a-div-using-flexbox-property-of-css/